# How to show a youtube channel live streaming in your react native app

Tags: react-native, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a youtube channel in which I go live with my viewers. I have built a react native app in which I want whenever I go live on my youtube channel then the live streaming should play in my app too. I really have no idea about how can I achieve it. Kindly guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you should go with a new [react-native-youtube-iframe](https://github.com/LonelyCpp/react-native-youtube-iframe) package. It provides webview wrapper for YouTube iframe video.

You can also use some youtube package using native solutions if you will have any performance problems.